# understand a SPRING DATA JPA (dao layer) project

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I want to understand a project's DAO layer, it's developed with Spring Data JPA.
I will take the entity `user` as example. So I have this Interface named
`userRepository extends JpaRepository<user, Long>`

What's the (User, Long) for? And secondly

```
@Query("select u from user u where u.login = :login")
User findUserByLogin(@Param("login")String login);
```

I can't find an Implementation of this Interface in the project. Are we going to work with this Interface directly to get data from DB?

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to spring data jpa documentation:

> The central interface in Spring Data repository abstraction is
>   Repository. It takes the **domain class** to manage as well as the
>   **id type** of the domain class as type arguments

So, **Utilisateur, Long** represents that your entity is Utilisateur and Long is the type of your primary key.
Regrading to your second question, spring offers default implmentations of those interfaces by creating proxy instances for them. Take a look at [spring data docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Comment: so what I have understood is : in a service class, if i created an attribute (ex: UserRepository user; ) so if i user a method (findUserByLogin) the method will use the Query and I will get the Data that I want,
but why I have the annotation :
@Autowired
 private UserRepository userDao;

Comment: @Autowired injects UserRepository dependency into your service bean. Seriously, read the spring documentation and of course learn about some basic best practices in software engineering like Dependency Injection.